# List of running Stored Procedures MySql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Is there a way to get list of running Stored Procedures in MySql ? its because my Stored Procedures would call from event scheduler.
Thanks

Comment: Have you had a look at [SHOW PROCESSLIST](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-processlist.html)?

Comment: I couldn't find anything related to my question, Would you please guide me.

Comment: I could have misunderstood your question. a) Do you want a list of the stored procedures you're calling from event scheduler? b) Or do you want the list of currently executed procedures? I thought you were interested in b)